# How to list the text property of a list item in a spinner

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner which i need to populate with children names from an sqlite database. I have a method to return a list of children.

```
public List<ChildUser> getChildren() {
        List<ChildUser> childList = new ArrayList<ChildUser>();

        //select columns
        String[] tableColumns = new String[]{"id", "childname", "nickname"};

        Cursor cursor = db.query("child", tableColumns, "parent =? ", new String[]{_parentName}, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();

        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            ChildUser child = new ChildUser();
            //take values from database
            child.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            child.setChildName(cursor.getString(1));
            child.setNickName(cursor.getString(2));


            //add to db
            childList.add(child);

            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return childList;
    }
```

I then call this method from a fragment to populate a spinner, however, i am getting another property of the childlist dispayed, how can i display the text property of my selected item in the spinner? (Please click the link to see exactly what my spinner displays)

```
 final ChildDataBase cdb = new ChildDataBase(getActivity());

        final List<ChildUser> childList = cdb.getChildren();



        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) v.findViewById(R.id.del_child_spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<ChildUser> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<ChildUser>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, childList);
        spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                childId = childList.get(position).getId();

                Toast succ = Toast.makeText(Home.super.getContext(), childList.get(position).getChildName() + " Selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                succ.show();


                return;
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                Toast succ = Toast.makeText(Home.super.getContext(), "No child selected.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                succ.show();
            }
        });
```

[Spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFcqL.jpg) <--- Click Here to see spinner

I also have a custom list adapter, im not sure if i can apply it somehow to get this task done.

```
/**
 * Created by Victor on 4/3/2016.
 */
public class ChildListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ChildUser> {

    private FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
    private android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    private final Context context;

    private final List<ChildUser> childList;

    public ChildListAdapter(Context context, List<ChildUser> childList){
        super(context, R.layout.fragment_child_list_layout, childList);//fragment_child_list
        this.context = context;
        this.childList= childList;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_child_list_layout,parent,false);


        Button childName = (Button)rowView.findViewById(R.id.childButton);
        childName.setText(childList.get(position).getNickName());

        childName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            public void onClick(View v) {
                String selectedChild = childList.get(position).getChildName();
                // do something with selected item
                Toast fail = Toast.makeText(ChildListAdapter.super.getContext(), selectedChild + " selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                fail.show();
                Globals._selectChild = selectedChild;
                TaskList taskList = new TaskList();
                fragmentTransaction = ((FragmentActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragholder, taskList);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();

            }
        });


        return rowView;


    }




}
```

This is my ChildUser object

```
public class ChildUser {
    String childName;
    String nickName, gender, parent;
    int id, age;

    public void setChildName(String childName)
    {
        this.childName = childName;
    }
    public String getChildName()
    {
        return this.childName;
    }
    public void setNickName(String nickName)
    {
        this.nickName = nickName;
    }
    public String getNickName()
    {
        return this.nickName;
    }
    public void setGender(String gender)
    {
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    public String getGender()
    {
        return this.gender;
    }
    public void setParent(String parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }
    public String getParent()
    {
        return this.parent;
    }
    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public int getId()
    {
        return this.id;
    }
    public void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }
    public int getAge()
    {
        return this.age;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this happens because you call `super` in your Constructor, Comment it & see if it helps

Comment: in my childlistadapter? if i comment it out i get alot of errors

Comment: do you want the data which is saved in sqlite is populated in spinner

Comment: ... You don't even use your custom `Adapter`, you use the internal one, which requires a String List Resource. Since you give it your custom object, it simply calls `toString()` on it, which you can see in your app,

Comment: yes but the data includes id, childname, nickname, ..i just want to display the childname in the spinner.

Comment: i tried returning the childnames as a string to a String array bit this does not  give me access to the childId when i select the item from the spinner

Comment: How can i implement by custom adapter to have access to those properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing the string returned by the toString() method of your class.

You can override toString() and return the correct value, otherwise you will need to implement your own custom adapter, or build a string array with the correct property instead of passing the model list to the arrayAdapter.

The easiest is to override toString()

```
public class ChildUser {
    String childName;
    String nickName, gender, parent;
    int id, age;

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.childName;
    }
/*.......*/
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I cant believe it was that simple! Thank you so much. wish i clould upvote your answer but im not there yet :/